# Is it inappropriate at all for someone in my client organization to email their PEM file to me?

Tags: certificates, email, saml, pem

I have a SAML offering for my clients to access my cloud based application. Should I have a portal for them to upload their certificates or should I go the easy route and just have them e-mail them to me? What would be the best practice for this case?

Comment: PEM files may contain private keys in addition to public keys (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539625/does-pem-file-contain-both-private-and-public-keys for more info).  If the PEM file contains public keys only, then there is nothing wrong with emailing the PEM file - after all, the contents are intended to be public.  But, if the PEM file contains a private key, then emailing the PEM file would not be advised.

Comment: @mti2935 - you should move your comment to "Your Answer". It's a perfectly valid answer... And one that is "sufficient" IMO - very little (if anything) to be added after.